# Is it possible to use Loaders class in MapActivity?

Tags: android

I have an android app to regularly record locations and store in a db in the background. db comes with content provider. use alarm receiver and service to set repetitive record task.

Now I'd like to put pins on a map using data(lat&long) in the db. I currently use a Loader to load the cursor and read data from db and then put them into a list view in a `fragment activity` (using support package v13 in 2.3.3 platform). However I could not figure out a way to convert this into drawing on a map view in a map acvivity instead. If my activity extends `MapActivity`, I cannot use method `getSupporLoaderManager().iniLoader(...)` to initialize the loader as it says error.

I want to keep the loader because it seems it processes faster if data size is large. My question is, how to read data using `Loader` class in `MapActivity`? If not possible, what is a better way to read data and draw on the map?

Any suggestion or answer appreciated.

Comment: Yes, on API Level 11 and higher.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you mean to use `Fragment`?

Comment: The Android Support package requires you to inherit from `FragmentActivity`, and you need that in order to access the `Loader` framework via the Android Support package. The Google Maps add-on requires you to inherit from `MapActivity`. You cannot do both at once.

Answer (score 0):

this should be possible! I assume you can load your list of data inside your MapActivity, so lets call the `Marker` for further reference. Just take a drawable to represent them and extend [ItemizedOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay)

```
public class MarkerOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{

  Collection<Marker> mMarkers;

  public MarkerOverlay(Drawable drawable, Collection<Marker> markers){
    super(drawable);
    mMarkers = marker;
  }

  @Override
  public OverlayItem createItem(int index){
    Marker m = mMarkers.get(index);
    return new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(m.getLatitude(), m.getLongitude()),
                           m.getTitle(), m.getSnippet();
  }

  @Override
  public int size(){
    return mMarkers.size();
  }

}
```

inside your MapActivity you can do this:

```
MarkerOverlay mMarkerOverlay;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
  super(icicle);
  ArrayList<Marker> list = Cursor.getList(); //fetch your data from Cursor
  mMarkerOverlay = new MarkerOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(
                               R.drawable.some_marker_drawable),
                               list);
  getOverlays().add(mMarkerOverlay); 

}
```

you could further have a unique drawable for each Marker. just set it in createItem before you return it

Comment: thanks for such a detailed explanation! However, my problem is how to use `Loader` class to fetch data from db in a `MapActivity`.

Comment: argh, sorry, I missed that. I leave my answer as it may help another one.